# Testing codes inside rxjs operator

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm new to angular jasmine test and I want to start using it on my app but I'm having problem with including rxjs operator on the test coverage.

```
saveChanges(){
  this.isSaveSuccessful = false;
  this.saveService.httpGetCall()
   .pipe(tap( ret =>{
        line 1;
        line 2;
      }),
      map( ret => {
        line 3;
        line 4;
    }),
     finalize(()=>{
      if(someBoolean) this.isSaveSuccessful = true;
     })).subscribe()
}
```

Line 1, 2, 3, 4 is not included on the test.

```
it('should save',()=>{
  component.saveChanges();
  expect(component.isSaveSuccessful).toBeTrue();
})
```

Comment: I think you need 2 things: 1) Mock the response from `httpGetCall` with different values in order to increase coverage 2) `fixture.detectChanges()` in order to respond to the changes made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock `saveService` in Jasmine and provide it for your component/service via Dependency Injection (DI):

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let saveService: SaveService:

  const yourCustomHttpGetCallResult = ...;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const saveServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('SaveService', {
      httpGetCall: of(yourCustomHttpGetCallResult),
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SaveService, useValue: saveServiceMock },
      ],
    });

    // create a component fixture
    ...

    saveService = TestBed.inject(SaveService);
  });

  it('should cover the lines 1, 2, 3, 4', () => {
    component.saveChanges();
  });

  it('should call saveChanges with another result', () => {
    const newCustomValue = ...;
    saveService.httpGetCall.and.returnValue(of(newCustomValue));

    component.saveChanges();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mock what is returned from the this.saveService.httpGetCall(),
Here is a full detailed explanation on how to do that.
https://angular.io/guide/http

then, once that is mocked you could do something like this.

```
it('should save',()=>{
  component.saveChanges();
  mockedHttp.subscribe(result => {
   expect(result).toBe("your desired result");
  })
  expect(component.isSaveSuccessful).toBeTrue();
})
```